# awk-Printing column value without new line and adding comma

Tags: text-processing, awk

input.txt

```
 EN1
 EN2
 EN3
 EN4
 EN5
```

output

```
EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5
```

I have tried awk.But it is not printing with comma

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = ","} { printf $1}' input.txt
```

I have GNU Awk 4.0.0 version

Comment: Strange, ORS should separate the line (records) with commas, it's hard to believe v 4.0 of gawk would change that .. but it looks that way based on your experience.

Comment: So you were *not* looking for an awk solution ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","}1' input.txt
```

yields this:

```
EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5,
```

so *is* printing with a comma (so I'm not sure I understand your comment in your post about this not happening) though I suspect the trailing comma is a problem.

Tested with GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: It is printing without comma eg. EN1EN2EN3EN4EN5

Comment: what version of awk are you using? This is odd, since I pasted this in from the console.

Comment: The question has used `OFS`, this answer uses `ORS` .. that explains the difference in behaviour... `printf` doesn't produce an ORS

Answer (score 5):

I know, old topic, but I could not resist - here's yet another short and simple way to do this:

```
$ paste -sd, input.txt
EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5
$
```

Works on Linux and Solaris, maybe even on other platforms.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tr` in such situation.

```
tr '\n' ',' <input.txt
```

This replaces the final newline by a comma as well. To avoid this, on Linux, if you know that the input file does end with a newline:

```
<input.txt head -c -1 | tr '\n' ,
```

Add `; echo` if you want the output to be terminated by a newline.

Alternatively, you can get the shell to remove a trailing comma if there is one.

```
columns=$(<input.txt tr '\n' ',')
echo "${columns%,}"
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this gives me an "extra operand" error message, but `tr '\n' ',' < input.txt` works fine, but also with a trailing comma.

Comment: @Levon See my edit

Comment: @Gilles Neat .. works nice (don't come often across a command that starts with `<`)

Answer (score 3):

There's also `xargs` and `sed`:

```
$ xargs <input.txt | sed -e 's/ /,/g'
EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5
```

An advantage here is that there is no trailing comma to get rid of.

`xargs` to combine the input lines, `sed` to replace all spaces with commas.  I use this routinely to construct regular expressions (replace spaces with `|`) and quick sums to pipe into `bc` (replace spaces with `+`).

(FYI `xargs` defaults to `echo` as the command if none is provided)

NOTE: This only works if the input file is as described (one field per line, no spaces).  If there are more fields and/or spaces in the input you can use awk or sed to pre-process the input.  For example, with input like this:

```
EN1 foo bar
EN2 bar foo
EN3 baz quux
EN4 abc def
EN5 hij klm
```

Here awk is used to extract only the first field:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' input.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g'
EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5
```

In this second (sed) example, spaces in the original input are replaced with some other string (chosen as unlikely to be in the original input), then fed into xargs.  sed then replaces the spaces added by xargs, and then restores the strings from the input:

```
$ sed -e 's/ /--space--/g' input.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/--space--/ /g'
EN1 foo bar,EN2 bar foo,EN3 baz quux,EN4 abc def,EN5 hij klm
```

---

Now for some gratuitous op-ed commentary:

One of the most useful pieces of knowledge about unix text processing tools is that you can and should should think of data as being almost infinitely malleable - you can transform it into whatever form you need either to provide input to another process or to produce the output you want or both.

This is part of the reason why unix people tend to hate proprietary data formats - it's not just a philosophical disapproval or a wish to avoid vendor lock-in, it's also the very pragmatic fact that they make it difficult for us to manipulate and use *our* data in ways that weren't foreseen by the software's developers.

Comment: It won't be a problem in most cases, and it is certainly very useful for what you have mentioned, but it does output a trailing `\n`, and if `xargs` needs to invoke `echo` multiple times due to command-line args limits, `sed` will introduce more spurious `\n`s; one for each extra call ...(+1 BTW)

Comment: PS.. I just noticed that `xargs echo -n` avoids the `\n` issue...  but *sed* can hit a memory limit (it did in my rather large scale tests), so it should be fine if you aren't dealing with gigabyte+ long command lines ;)

Comment: yeah, well, xargs will split them long before command lines get to a gigabyte :).  I've occasionally run into problems when generating huge command lines from `find /really/stupidly/long/path/.../ | xargs` but that's more an issue with the command i'm feeding it into than with xargs (e.g. 'du -sh' may generate multiple total lines which then need to be added), and is solvable with a suitable wrapper script or post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that doesn't print a comma at the end of the line:

`{printf("%s", NR == 1 ? $0 : ","$0);} END {printf("\n");} file`

**Explanation**

When the first line is seen (`NR == 1`), only it is printed; otherwise a comma and the line are sent as arguments to `printf`.

This solution uses `AWK`'s ternary operator `?:`, that is:

`NR == 1 ? $0 : ","$0`

If the `NR` variable is equal to `1`, then it sends the first line as the argument to `printf`; else it sends a comma concatenated with the current line.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe '(eof)?s/\s+$//:s/\s+$/,/' input.txt
```

*output:* no trailing `\n`

```
EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g' input.txt
```

The `-z` option (only in sed version 4.2 or later) expects zero-byte as the end of record character instead of the newline character, treating this whole input file as a single line.
Search for `\n` (newline character) and replace with comma. The `g` makes the search-replace global.

It converts the final newline character to a comma too, but it's easy to convert the final comma back:

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g' input.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

The `$` symbol marks the end of the line, so it replaces the final comma with a newline character.

Note that if your input file does contain any zero-bytes (often used in binary files to terminate strings) then this will see them as end of record markers. The example above shouldn't be affected, but in some situations it can give unexpected results.