# How to export variables that are set, all at once?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, set

`set` command displays all the local variables like below. How do I export these variables all at once?

```
>set
a=123
b="asd asd"
c="hello world"
```

Comment: what do you mean export all at once? you can use semi colons to define in one line...like a=123;b="asd asd";c="hello world"

Comment: Very similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79064/4667

Comment: `set` also displays functions and system variables like BASH_VERSION

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is that an excerpt of `set` output you're showing? If so, then it's not `bash`'s. Do you want to export all the currently set variable including the special shell variables? Or only those 3 variables like in `export a b c`?

Comment: `export ${!T*}` would export any defined parameter whose name starts with `T`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to easily generate a list of *all* defined parameters.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Run the following command, before setting the variables:

```
set -a
set -o allexport  # self-documenting version
```

[man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> `-a`
> When this option is on, the export attribute shall be set for each variable to which an assignment is performed
>
> `-o option-name`
> Set the option corresponding to `option-name`:
>
> - `allexport`
>   Same as `-a`.

To turn this option off, run `set +a` or `set +o allexport` afterwards.

Example:

```
set -a  # or: set -o allexport 
. ./environment
set +a
```

Where `environment` contains:

```
FOO=BAR
BAS='quote when using spaces, (, >, $, ; etc'
```

Comment: This must be enabled before assigning to variables, though. It doesn't do anything to previously assigned variables.

Comment: @chepner , Thanks i forgot to mention that !!

Comment: This also automatically exports functions in the same way as `function example(){ echo good; }; export -f example`

Answer (score 8):

Same preliminary requirement as chosen answer ... either explicitly export each variable as per

```
export aaaa=1234
```

or prior to any variable assignment issue

```
set -a  #  for details see answer by @nitin
```

then this works if your shell is bash ( possibly other shells as well )

```
export > /my/env/var/file
```

your new file will contain a dump of all currently defined variables ...  with entries like

```
declare -x PORT="9000"
declare -x PORT_ADMIN="3001"
declare -x PORT_DOCKER_REGISTRY="5000"
declare -x PORT_ENDUSER="3000"
declare -x PRE_BUILD_DIR="/cryptdata6/var/log/tmp/khufu01/loud_deploy/curr/loud-build/hygge"
declare -x PROJECT_ID="hygge"
declare -x PROJECT_ID_BUSHIDO="bushido"
```

then to jack up current shell with all those env vars issue

```
source  /my/env/var/file
```

Comment: I believe `export` only prints variables that are already (marked to be) exported, while I believe the question is about variables that are set, but not marked to be exported. I just tested this on bash, which prints nothing: `FOOBAR=x; export | grep FOOBAR`.

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman good catch I updated to qualify my answer

Answer (score 5):

```
`echo "export" $((set -o posix ; set)|awk -F "=" 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}1 $1~/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ {print $1}')`
```

1. First, get all set environment variables: `(set -o posix ; set)`
   Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/420295/how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-currently-defined-environment-variables-in-a-linux-ba
2. Get all environment variable names, separated by space: `awk -F "=" 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}1 $1~/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ {print $1}'`
   Reference: [awk-Printing column value without new line and adding comma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44716/awk-printing-column-value-without-new-line-and-adding-comma) and
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212993/regular-expression-to-match-a-pattern-inside-awk-command
3. Now, we need to export these variables, but xargs can not do this because it forks child process, export have to be run under current process. `echo "export" ...` build a command we want, then use `` to run it. That's all :p.

Comment: Welcomme to U&L SE. Maybe you can edit your post and give some explication.

Comment: It's not correct to assume environment variable names will consist solely of a-z and A-Z.  They commonly include underscores and digits as well, so the pattern would be `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`.  There are some variations on this based on the shell you're using, but this is the safe / portable approach.

Comment: Good point @ChrisJohnson - updated!

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend `export` to the variable name via `awk` and `eval` the resulting output:

```
eval $(printenv | awk -F= '{ print "export " $1 }')
```

Comment: `printenv` prints the variables that are already exported. That also won't work properly if there are variables that contain newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

`compgen -v` will print a list of all variable names so you can export them all with

```bsh
export $(compgen -v)
```

This will have various effects depending on the variables you have defined (ex: [`BASHOPTS` will get exported by this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304751/3920202)). Be wary of how you use this.

Comment: Or just `export $(compgen -v)` (also assuming an unmodified `$IFS`), bearing in mind that exporting bash builtin variables such as `SHELLOPTS` or `BASHOPTS` can have nasty consequences.

Comment: Thanks, I never realized `export` accepts multiple symbols. I've incorporated most of your comment into the answer.